# Pattern to transform objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, transformation

I am looking for some best practices/patterns to transform objects from one to another. I load the data from DB using DAO to create my domain objects. In my application I need to transform into a different object that acts as an input to another module.
For example, the customer is the domain object which holds a list of orders. I need to transform this into a object customerorder.

```
Public class Customer {
   String customerid
   List<Order> orders
}

Public class Order {
   Integer id
   Date orderDate
}

/** Transformed objects **/
public class CustomerOrder {
   string customerid
   Integer orderid
}
```

Currently I have an interface CustomerDTO which has a method to return a list of CustomerOrder objects and a concrete class implementing the interface

```
Public interface CustomerDTO {
   List<CustomerOrder> getData(Date date)
}

Public class CustomerDTOImpl implements CustomerDTO {
   Private Customer customer
   Public CustomerDTOImpl(Customer customer) {
      this.customer = customer
   }

   Public List<CustomerOrder> getData(Date date) {
       ..... Code to loop through orders and create and return a list with matching order dates
   }
}
```

For simple, transformations I don't need a DTO class but my transdormations are very complex and I would like to keep the transformation logic separate for different objects.
Initially I had a transformer class which just loops through all the objects and create transformed objects but I don't think that was a good design and thought of this DTO. But I believe there are better ways to do it.

Also I need to be able to use the DTO pattern on several objects. In this Customer was just one such object? I have 20 like diffent objects that I need to transform into their respective transformed objects.

Any thoughts on best practices and pattern would be very useful. Also is there any generics I could use to scale them better.

Thanks
Javid

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want a design pattern to help you deal with the fact that you're trying to work around the fact that your data model isn't designed well for the use cases you're trying to implement? I'm guessing you're kind of stuck with that, and it's your role to just make it work? <snark>This. This is why I don't take on large enterprise java projects anymore.</snark> I would suggest refactoring the architecture so you can make your data objects implement whatever interfaces are required by other modules. If that doesn't work, check out the Adapter pattern.

Comment: @BenTaitelbaum I agree partly. It's not the data model isn't designed perfectly but the transformation is quite comp,ex. By not changing my data model to reflect the end transformed object, I can support future transformation logic changes without altering my DAO or domain model. I will look into the Adapter pattern. Seems like my DTOImpl class may already be doing that. Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the object extend or implement another object so that you can cast them as different kinds of objects. I suggest looking into Polymorphism to do this. The name sounds scary, but it's no big deal

Answer (score 0):

Just write a new DAO that loads data from the DB into the correct domain objects.

Comment: @Jeff The transformation logic could change for another module, so making changes to the DAO may not be possible since the data is same for all modules, except each module needs to have a different transformation of same the data (Domain model)